# How to set toolbar subtitle in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have an application with a main activity which is mainly used as a navHost. I have a toolbar defined for the main activity and I can set title and subtitle in the main activity.

I also have three fragments which gets displayed by pressing items in a BottomNavigationView.

All of this working fine.

I need to set the  toolbar subtitle in each of these fragments. The code I have written after Googling compiles fine, but does not set the subtitle.

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

MainAcitvity:

```
const val DEBUG: Boolean = true
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navcontroller: NavController
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.main_toolbar)
        toolbar.setTitle("Carnatic Songs")
        toolbar.subtitle = "Songs"

//        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launch_icon)


        // Using the Navigation component of Jetpack. For this to work, the ids of the menu items are
        // to be exactly the same as the fragment ids

        navcontroller = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navcontroller)
}
```

The setting of the subtitle in the MainActivity is successful and it displyas.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    >

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

In the fragment, I am doing the following to set the subtitle:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.subtitle= noSongsDisplayed + " Songs"
```

But, the subtitle is not set. 
I tried it in onViewCreated as well as in onResume, but nothing works.

I am using androidx libraries.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You would need to set the `Toolbar` with ID `main_toolbar` as the support `ActionBar` for your `Fragment` code to work.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do I do that? When I try toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.main_toolbar), it says unresolved reference findViewByID

Comment: Oh, no, sorry, I meant in the `Activity`. It looks like you tried that there, but just with the wrong `R.id`. After you find your `toolbar` there, just call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks very much.